# Selection of sample on X or Y

Tags: regression, least-squares

In an OLS regression where Y is the dependent variable, X the independent variable and u the error term:

Selecting our sample on Y creates a bias:
If we have a Y variable that is zero mean and we only run our regression if y>0 our bias will be E(u|u>-xBeta)

What about when we select our sample on X ?
So we have a similar zero mean X variable, and we cut at x>0.
Does it create a bias ? Why not ?

Comment: Well it depends. If Y is a linear function of that X variable, then it certainly will affect which Y are selected, for instance.

Comment: That was my initial thought as well. But if I run a simulation in which I clearly define x as a  random variable and u as a 0 mean random variable and then define y=x+u: Any regression selecting on x will yield the expected coefficient of 1, while any regression selecting on y will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select on y you will more likely drop observations with positive errors, especially if the predicted value is high. So the negative errors will  in your observed dataset be more influential when the predicted y is high, and they will pull the regression line to a flatter trajectory.

A selection on x will not prefer observations with a particular error, so no bias occurs.